# Converting json file to a single line

Tags: json, apache-spark, dataframe, minify

I have a huge `.json` file like the one below. I want to convert that JSON to a dataframe on Spark.

```
{
    "movie": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test"
    }
}
```

When I execute the following code, I get a `_corrupt_record` error:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json("example.json")
df.first()
```

Lately I learned that Spark only supports one-line JSON files, like:

```
{ "movie": { "id": 1, "name": "test test" } }
```

How can I convert a JSON text from multiple lines to a single line.

Comment: replace the linebreaks with an empty string